# `obj.f(null)` in Java bytecode

Tags: java, bytecode

Is it safe to assume that `obj.f(null)` is always compiled to 2 **consecutive** instructions

```
ACONST_NULL
INVOKEVIRTUAL <type-of-obj> f <descriptor-of-f>
```

by `javac`, no matter where `obj.f(null)` appears in source code and how it is intermingled with other source code?

EDIT: I don't intend to do nullability check. I don't care about `Object a = null; obj.f(a);`.

---

EDIT: @OliverCharlesworth asked for my original problem. I want to detect `obj.f(null)` in bytecode with asm library. One can easily think of 2 ways of solving this problem.

1. Use `AnalyzerAdapter` to verify whether the last element in stack is of type `NULL` when interested `INVOKEVIRTUAL` is called. This certainly works, but involves expanding stack frames, and is more expensive.
2. Detect `ACONST_NULL` followed by `INVOKEVIRTUAL`. It probably works. But I'm not sure. Therefore, I'm asking the question here.

Comment: I don't know.  But this sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) to me...

Comment: What I mean is; it seems unlikely that your question is the actual problem you're facing; what are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: What about `Object a = null; obj.f(a);`? If you are saying you are trying to detect `null` as an argument with bytecode analysis, it's a hard problem.

Comment: @Radiodef I don't intend to do nullability check. It's okay to leave this one out. Good point though.

Comment: How can we possibly answer this? Perhaps it always does today, tomorrow there could be a new compiler.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to GUARANTEE that it turns into exactly that sequence.  The compiler could decide to insert some other instructions in-between.  However, that seems unlikely 99.99% of the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `obj.f` is a non static, non interface, non superclass, non private method non inner/outer class method (edit: And also non varargs), then yes, I think it is safe to assume in practice. Of course, `javac` could always be changed tomorrow, but it is hard to immagine changing this, since it is the simplest and most natural way to compile the corresponding code.

Note that if any of the conditions listed above are true, it will probably be compiled differently. For example a static method will obviously use `invokestatic` instead of `invokevirtual`. If the method is being invoked on an outer class from an inner class, it will probably call a compiler generated synthetic method instead, and so on.

Comment: All your assumptions are true. And I understand how each of these can affect the result. Sorry I didn't say these in the question.

Comment: You may add varargs methods to the list of exceptions. Further, it’s worth noting the ambiguity in the opposite direction; finding a sequence of `ACONST_NULL`, `INVOKEVIRTUAL foo` does not guaranty that the source code looked like `foo(null);`…

Comment: @Holger Thanks, I forgot about that one.

Comment: @Holger Why is this: finding a sequence of` `ACONST_NULL`, `INVOKEVIRTUAL foo` does not guaranty that the source code looked like `foo(null);`

Comment: @Haozhun That sequence just means the last argument of foo is null. It could look anything like `(null).foo()` to `foo.(bar, baz, blah, null)` depending on the airity of foo.

Comment: @Haozhun: it’s also possible that the source code has artifacts that don’t appear in the byte code, e.g. an expression like `foo((SomeType)null)` might invoke a different overloaded method than `foo(null)` while both expressions will produce the bytecode `ACONST_NULL`, `INVOKEVIRTUAL foo`, yet with a different `foo` (if it’s the same `foo`, the type cast had no effect at all)…

Comment: Thanks. I get it. As long as descriptor and owner is checked, these doesn't seem like problems.